# How to create universal privilege managing sytem for Spring MVC controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, boilerplate

I am doing a browser based game.
Lets say I have a spring controller lots of controllers ~10. And each has like 10 url mappings. Thats like 100+ mapping methods.

Each mapping would only load or display the correct content if certain rules are fulfilled. Rules would be checked by doing DB queries. **For example**:

I am level 12 User and have each controller allow to show content only if user is level 10+, 20+, 30+, 40+, 50+ etc.

I could do it by doing the query under every mapping method in every controller, but there would be way too much of **boilerplating**.

**Is there a way to do it somehow centrilized, like keep my restriction mapping somewhere together and don't have to put it under every url mapping method?**

Even if there probably isn't such thing by design, maybe you have had the same issue yourself and have come up with some clever solution?

Comment: I could see `HMVC` dealing with this pretty well. If user is above a certain level, call the higher level controller, if not, continue with lower level one.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use `spring-security` with a custom `PermissionEvaluator` so you could basically use the same implementation in both webpages and controllers:
in the webpage you could use: 
`<security:authorize access="hasPermission(#shop,'see')"></security:authorize>`
in your controller and in any of your service methods you could use:
`@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#shop,'see')")`

like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#shop,'see')")
@RequestMapping("/someUrl")
public String processSomeUrl(@ModelAttribute("shop") Shop shop){
    shop.getStuff();
}
```

or also `@PostAuthorize` and `@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject,'see')")` (to filter lists)

All of these function will either restrict access or filter result list according to you own permission evaluator. They will all point to the same implementation, which would look something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        logger.info("hasPermission "+auth+" - "+arg1+" - "+arg2+" ");
        if(arg2 instanceof String && arg1 instanceof Shop){
            Shop shop = (Shop)arg1;
            if(((String) arg2).equals("see")){
                //here you can have your own function
                boolean result = hasPermissionSeeShop(auth, project);                   
                return result;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication arg0, Serializable arg1,
        String arg2, Object arg3) {
        logger.info("hasPermission "+arg0+" - "+arg1+" - "+arg2+" - "+arg3+" ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, when these methods return false it automatically throws an AccessDeniedException and you can easily configure that to redirect to your own accessDenied page in the http element:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="accessDeniedPage"/>
</http>
```

Comment: How does `#shop` end up being a `Shop` object? Like, when you write it, its just a string...

Comment: in a controller or a service, you can use #shop in the hasPermission to refer to an argument `Shop shop` of your method (has to have the same name). and in you webPage #shop refers to the variable `${shop}`. you could always use just strings if you dont't want to use objects

Comment: How do i get the current shop(in my case User) to controller method arguments?

Comment: do you use spring security already in your application? if so you should link your user profile to the authentication provided by spring-security. You don't have to pass your user object. it will already be in authentication and populated automatically. shop was more an object the User needs permission to see. hasPermission(#shop,'see') means "does the authenticated user (via authentication object) have permission to 'see' this #shop?"